# Passing @PathParam to Sub Resource locator class in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to call my api endpoint this way:

```
http://.../companies/1/employees
```

and retrieve the employees of company with code 1. I have this code:

```
@Path("companies")
public class CompanyResource {

    @Context
    ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @GET
    @Path("{idCompany}/employees")
    public EmployeeResource getEmployees() {
        return resourceContext.getResource(EmployeeResource.class);
    }

}
```

and

```
@Path("/employees")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @PathParam("idCompany")
    String idCompany;

    @GET
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        // here "idCompany" is null
        //some code
    }
}
```

But the path param is null. What am I doing wrong? Is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: What peeskillet explains is demonstrated here quite clearly, search for "Example 3.18. sub-resource locators": https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2464

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the null id, but there are a couple things to point out

- `@GET` should be removed from the `EmployeeResource getEmployees()` method. Sub Resource locators shouldn't have HTTP method annotations. See [Sub-resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2464)
- Also the `@Path` on the `EmployeeResource` is ignored (not needed). Not a problem, just thought you should know.

Below a complete working example using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html). Here are the test dependencies I used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can run it like any other JUnit test

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

public class LocatorTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static class Employee {
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public Employee(){}
        public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }

    public static class Company {
        public String companyId;
        public List<Employee> employees;
        public Company(){}
        public Company(String companyId, List<Employee> employees) {
            this.companyId = companyId;
            this.employees = employees;
        }
    }

    @Path("companies")
    public static class CompanyResource {

        @Context
        private ResourceContext resourceContext;

        @Path("{companyId}/employees")
        public EmployeeResource getEmployees() {
            return resourceContext.getResource(EmployeeResource.class);
        }
    }

    public static class EmployeeResource {

        @PathParam("companyId")
        public String companyId;

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Company getCompanyEmployees() {
            List<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();
            emps.add(new Employee("pee", "skillet"));
            emps.add(new Employee("Stack", "Overflow"));
            Company co = new Company(companyId, emps);
            return co;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(CompanyResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void doit() {
        Response response = target("companies/1234/employees").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        Company co = response.readEntity(Company.class);
        assertNotNull(co.companyId);
        assertEquals("1234", co.companyId);
        assertEquals(2, co.employees.size());
        response.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a summary of possible solutions with JAX-RS 2.0:

- **Request scoped sub resource with constructor:**

  ```
  @Path("companies")
  public class CompanyResource {

      @Path("{idCompany}/employees")
      public EmployeeResource getEmployees(@PathParam("idCompany") String companyId) {
          return new EmployeeResource(companyId);
      }
  }  

  public class EmployeeResource {

      private String companyId

      public EmployeeResource(String companyId) {
          this.companyId = companyId;
      }

      @GET
      public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
          //some code
      }
  }
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - no dependency injection
- **Request scoped sub resource with [ResourceContext#initResource(Class)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html#initResource-T-):**

  ```
  @Path("companies")
  public class CompanyResource {

      @Context
      private ResourceContext resourceContext;

      @GET
      @Path("{idCompany}/employees")
      public EmployeeResource getEmployees(@PathParam("idCompany") String companyId) {
          EmployeeResource employeeResource = new EmployeeResource(companyId);
          return resourceContext.initResource(employeeResource);
      }
  }  

  public class EmployeeResource {

      @Context
      private Request request;

      private String companyId

      public EmployeeResource(String companyId) {
          this.companyId = companyId;
      }

      @GET
      public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
          //some code
      }
  }
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - no dependency injection with [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)
- **Request scoped sub resource with [ResourceContext#getResource(Class)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html#getResource-java.lang.Class-):**

  ```
  @Path("companies")
  public class CompanyResource {

      @Context
      private ResourceContext resourceContext;

      @GET
      @Path("{idCompany}/employees")
      public EmployeeResource getEmployees(@PathParam("idCompany") String companyId) {
          EmployeeResource employeeResource = resourceContext.getResource(EmployeeResource.class);
          employeeResource.setCompanyId(companyId);
          return employeeResource;
      }
  }  

  public class EmployeeResource {

      @Context
      private Request request;

      private String companyId

      public setCompanyId(String companyId) {
          this.companyId = companyId;
      }

      @GET
      public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
          //some code
      }
  }
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - no dependency injection with [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)
- **Request scoped sub resource with [`@PathParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) as field:**

  ```
  @Path("companies")
  public class CompanyResource {

      @Context
      private ResourceContext resourceContext;

      @GET
      @Path("{idCompany}/employees")
      public EmployeeResource getEmployees() {
          return resourceContext.getResource(EmployeeResource.class);
      }
  }  

  public class EmployeeResource {

      @Context
      private Request request;

      @PathParam("idCompany")
      private String companyId;

      @GET
      public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
          // some code
      }
  }
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - no dependency injection with [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)
- **Request scoped sub resource with return type `Class<T>`:**

  ```
  @Path("companies")
  public class CompanyResource {

      @GET
      @Path("{idCompany}/employees")
      public Class<EmployeeResource> getEmployees() {
          return EmployeeResource.class;
      }
  }  

  public class EmployeeResource {

      @Context
      private Request request;

      @PathParam("idCompany")
      private String companyId;

      @GET
      public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
          // some code
      }
  }
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - no dependency injection with [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)
- **Request scoped sub resource with [`@PathParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) as method parameter:**

  ```
  @Path("companies")
  public class CompanyResource {

      @Context
      private ResourceContext resourceContext;

      @GET
      @Path("{idCompany}/employees")
      public Class<EmployeeResource> getEmployees() {
          return resourceContext.getResource(EmployeeResource.class);
      }
  }  

  public class EmployeeResource {

      @Context
      private Request request;

      @GET
      public List<Employee> getEmployees(@PathParam("idCompany") String companyId) {
          // some code
      }
  }
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - no dependency injection with [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)
- **Singleton sub resource with [`@PathParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) as method parameter:**

  ```
  @Path("companies")
  public class CompanyResource {

      @Context
      private ResourceContext resourceContext;

      @GET
      @Path("{idCompany}/employees")
      public Class<EmployeeResource> getEmployees() {
          return resourceContext.getResource(EmployeeResource.class);
      }
  }  

  @Singleton
  public class EmployeeResource {

      @Context
      private Request request;

      @GET
      public List<Employee> getEmployees(@PathParam("idCompany") String companyId) {
          // some code
      }
  }
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - no dependency injection with [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)

See also:

- [Jersey User Guide - Rules of Injection](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2682)
- [Jersey User Guide - sub-resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2464)
- [Java EE 7 and JAX-RS 2.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jaxrs20-1929352.html)
- [JAX_RS_SPEC-55](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_RS_SPEC-55)

Comment: I scrolled down the whole answer to look for option which allows DI.

Comment: @Pawan: With JAX-RS 2.0 it is not possible, but maybe with Java EE  8 and JAX-RS 2.1 it is possible. See https://speakerdeck.com/mkarg/jax-rs-2-dot-1-new-features-whats-in-the-queue-for-rest-in-java-ee-8-jfs-2015

Comment: You can also do `Resource.from(YourResource.class)`. My dependencies are injected and both name binding and method interception also work. All of the other options had one or more features that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I use path param like this

```
@GET
public List<Employee> getEmployees(@PathParam("idCompany") String id ) {
    // here "idCompany" is null
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how I usually do it :

```
@Path("companies")
public class CompanyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{idCompany}/employees")
    public EmployeeResource getEmployees(@PathParam("idCompany") String idCompany) {
       // ...
    }

}
```

or

```
@Path("companies/{idCompany}/employees")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @PathParam("idCompany")
    String idCompany;

    @GET
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
       //
    }
}
```

the `@PathParam` is null in the second example because in order to inject it in a field, the `@Path` annotation on the service class must have a section declaring the `{idCompany}` `@PathParam`.